Using if-then-else in Program Definition's obligation
Consider the following program (which is a simpler version of what I'm trying to do):
Require Import List Arith.

Program Definition test (l: list nat) : nat :=
  if (existsb (fun x => Nat.eqb x 1) l) then
    match l with
      | a::_ => a
      | nil => _
    end
  else 0.
Next Obligation.
  
Qed.

It should be simple to prove that the second case (nil) cannot happen because of the if-condition. However, in the obligation, I only see
Goal (1)
---
nat

The condition is not mentioned, so there is no way to derive a contradiction. (Of course I do not just want to provide a default value because this would not work in the more complex case).
How can I get hold of the if-condition and use it in fulfilling the obligation?

Can you give a minimal working example? In particular, one that includes your imports, so that your example type-checks?

Right. This should do it.

You will probably have to use existsb_exists at some point. If this were Agda, I would tell you to use with ... in or the inspect idiom to get the required equality. Coq users apparently call this the convoy pattern?

See also here, here and here.

I've found that if I want to use if-then-else facts later in a definition, I have to use decidable facts.
For example, in this case:
Definition has_one (l: list nat) :=
  exists a, In a l /\ a = 1.

Definition has_one_dec (l: list nat): {has_one l} + {~ has_one l}.
Proof.
  case (existsb (fun x => Nat.eqb x 1) l) eqn:A.
  * left. apply existsb_exists in A. destruct A. exists x. intuition. now apply Nat.eqb_eq.
  * right. intro. apply Bool.eq_true_false_abs in A. auto.
    apply existsb_exists. destruct H. exists x. intuition. now apply Nat.eqb_eq.
Qed.

Now, doing if has_one_dec l will give me the fact one_dec l:
Program Definition test (l: list nat) : nat :=
  if has_one_dec l then
    match l with
      | a::_ => a
      | nil => _
    end
  else 0.

Next Obligation.
( Goal (1)
  h : has_one nil
  --- 
  nat
)
  apply constructive_indefinite_description in h. destruct h as [? []].
  simpl in H. now exfalso.
Qed.

(N.B.: in this case I need constructive_indefinite_description to make use of has_one because test returns a nat instead of a Prop)
